# Suggest me good books to learn heuristics to solve Operations Research problems using python

Tags: linear-programming, python, reference-request, heuristics

Suggest me some good books with implementation of heuristics using python to solve operations research problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chapter 7 of the book called **Artificial Intelligence with Python** by *Patreek Joshi* focuses on the heuristic search methods. Other than that, the following list of references can be considered for more details on Metaheuristics:

1. Clever Algorithms: Nature-Inspired Programming Recipes (by Jason Brownlee)
2. Essentials of Metaheuristics (by Sean Luke)
3. Hands-On Genetic Algorithms with Python: Applying genetic algorithms to solve real-world deep learning and artificial intelligence problems (by Eyal Wirsansky).

Also, there is an online course in Udemy: **Optimization with Metaheuristics in Python** which covers some of the well-known metaheuristics such as, SA, GA, Tabu search, and Evolutionary strategies. I think this online course will be a good point to start.

Answer (score 3):

The book [burke2005search] provides a good starting points for different heuristics algorithms. Identify the techniques you need first. Most likely, you can find a reliable open source package.

- [burke2005search] Burke, E. K., & Kendall, G. (2005). Search methodologies (pp. 1-17). Springer Science+ Business Media, Incorporated.